# Javascript Regex - match capital/upperacase letter in a middle of a word (in a sentence)?

Tags: javascript, regex, uppercase

I need to match all capital letters only if they are in a middle of the word. For exmaple `RegExr` would have a match for letter `E`. `someThings` for letter `T`.
If capital letter start at the start of of the word it should not match.

This regex almost match it, but it actually matches both lower case next to upper case letter.

```
/[a-z][A-Z]/g
```

For example for word `RegExr`, it matches `gE`, but I need to match only `E`.

**update**

Updated title to specify that this case happens in a sentence, not single word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to use non-word-boundaries here. Word characters (`\w`) are letters `[a-zA-Z]`, numbers `[0-9]` and the underscore `_`.

By using `\B[A-Z]\B` you can match every uppercase letter, that is inside a word. This will also match:

- `9Gag`
- `_H_ello`

Comment: Thanks, this look quite elegant regex.

Comment: It seems only one `\B` is enough (at the beginning). At least in http://regexr.com/ it matches the same pattern.

Comment: @Andrius depends on how you define _middle of the word_. For me `hellO` should give no match, but it will without the ending `\B`

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right, in that case it should not match.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
/\B[A-Z]\B/g
```

Use `\B` for word boundries

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/AzT9S9/4) for tests and explanation.

Comment: Middle of a word, not "not at the beginning of the string". This doesn't actually answer OP's question.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Updated (I thought his string contained one word)

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `RegExp.prototype.exec()` function:

```js
var str = 'RegExr someTextBetween JavaScript',
    matched = [],
    re = /[^A-Z\s]([A-Z])[^A-Z\s]/g;
    
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    matched.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matched);
```